# Ways to Retrieve Data from Database through Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and Spring.
I am trying to access data in Mysql using Hibernate Framework. But I feel confused which class to use to retrieve object.
Let me give examples. I found in some online tutorials and websites,

1 . Using **HibernateTemplate** as an interface to access Data

2. Using **Persistence**

   ```
   EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
       .createEntityManagerFactory("pl.edu.bogdan.training.db.entity");
   EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
   ```
3. Using **SessionFactory**

   ```
   package com.journaldev.dao;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.hibernate.*;
   import com.journaldev.model.Person;
   public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }

   @Override
   public void save(Person p) {
       Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       session.persist(p);
       tx.commit();
       session.close();
   }}
   ```

Could you please guide me in right way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're pretty much equivalent, at this point the only difference is the amount of code you need to write to access data.

Further you may need to fine-tune your queries. For example using `Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();` helps you control, which data manipulation / querying occurs within transaction, so that you don't hold connection to database too long. If you only need to save some entity, you may as well annotate the method of your bean with `@Transactional`.